# In Candy Box 2, I can't acess the castle and the hole

Tags: candy-box-2

I've done everything right, I beat the monkey, octopus, and myself. I just can't access the castle and the hole like I'm supposed to :/

Comment: Have you beaten The Forest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to complete **The Forest** to move on the the Castle entrance and the hole.

An easy way to complete The Forest is to use the *Monkey Wizard Staff* and the *Octopus King's Crown*. it is recommended to have 200 health with a Monkey Wizard Staff or a Octopus King's Crown otherwise with 350+ health

More info here:
https://candybox2.gamepedia.com/The_Forest